# Formating / manipulating a JSON response in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a service that returns this JSON object:

```
"[{"id":"1","name":"garage","parent":null},{"id":"2","name":"car","parent":"1"},{"id":"3","name":"engine","parent":"2"}]"
```

This is how it looks on Fiddler:

```
- JSON
    |- {}
        |-- id=1
        |-- name=garage
        |-- parent=(null)

    |- {}
        |-- id=2
        |-- name=car
        |-- parent=1

    |- {}
        |-- id=3
        |-- name=engine
        |-- parent=2
```

In the other hand, I have a JavaScript library that is expecting an object as below:

```
elements: {
  nodes: [
    { data: { id: '1', name: 'garage' } },
    { data: { id: '2', name: 'car' } },
    { data: { id: '3', name: 'engine' } }
  ], 

  edges: [
    { data: { id: '1', source: '1', target: '2' } },
    { data: { id: '2', source: '2', target: '3' } }
  ]
}
```

I tried to convert my JSON response to array using:

```
var jsonResponseAsArray = $.parseJSON(getJSON());
```

and then iterate it to format its contents:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonResponseAsArray.length; i++) {...}
```

Inside that for, I have tried many things such as creating objects and arrays to manipulate the structure without look. I have no idea how can I get some elements start with [{...}] such as the nodes elements, and others only with {} such as de data element.

Thanks,

Comment: Shows the real JSON and not what you saw in Fiddler

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this. I am sure there is a best/more elegant solution:

```
    var jsonResponseAsArray = $.parseJSON(getJSON());
    var elements = {}
    var obj = { "nodes": [], "edges": [] };

    for (var i = 0; i < jsonResponseAsArray.length; i++) {
        var data = {};
        var map = {};
        var data1 = {};
        var map1 = {};

        if (jsonResponseAsArray[i].parent != null) {
            map1["id"] = jsonResponseAsArray[i].id + jsonResponseAsArray[i].parent;
            map1["source"] = jsonResponseAsArray[i].id;
            map1["target"] = jsonResponseAsArray[i].parent;
            data1['data'] = map1;
            obj.edges.push(data1);
        }

        map["id"] = jsonResponseAsArray[i].id;
        map["name"] = jsonResponseAsArray[i].name;
        data['data'] = map
        obj.nodes.push(data);
    }

    elements["elements"] = obj;
    var elements = JSON.stringify(elements);
```